# Calculate walking points to reach target

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

- Given a number (finish end point), then an array of scooters, where scooters represents the position of the `ith scooter.`
- Each scooter can travel up to 10 points before the battery is fully discharged, and cannot go further. For example, if the scooter is at point 5, it can travel to points 5, 6, 7, ..., ., up to point 15 (inclusive), but not to point 16 or beyond.
- Calculate walking steps to reach the target.

Example1:

```
finish=23, scooters[7, 4, 14] 
output -> solution(finish, scooters) = 4
```

Explanation1:

- Starting from 0, the closest scooter is scooters[1] = 4 so it takes 4 points to walk there.
- Then the scooter can go up to 10 points, 10+4=14.
- There is a scooter at 14 points (scooters[2] = 14).
- This way we can go straight to the end to complete 23.
- So it's a total of 4 points of walking

Example2:

```
finish=27, scooters[15, 7, 3, 10]
output -> solution(finish, scooters) = 5
```

My Code:

```
finish=23
scooters = [7, 4, 14]

def solution(finish, scooters):
    sum = min(scooters)
    step = min(scooters)
    
    while sum < finish:
        step += 10
        sum = sum + step
    
    return step

solution(finish, scooters)
```

How to include `scooters[i]` within the while loop to check for the next available scooter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve consistency without too much logic is first `sort()`ing your list. After that you can calculate any distance between two scooters that has over 10 steps and add it to the sum:

```
def solution(finish, scooters):
    scooters.append(finish)
    scooters.sort()
    steps = scooters[0]
    for i in range(1, len(scooters)):
        if finish in (scooters[i], scooters[i - 1]):
            break
        steps += max(0, scooters[i] - scooters[i - 1] - 10)

    return steps

print(solution(27, [15, 7, 3, 10]))
# 5
print(solution(23, [7, 4, 14]))
# 4
print(solution(10, [15, 7, 3, 10]))
# 3
print(solution(2, [15, 3]))
# 2
```

Comment: Test out your algorithm for various inputs. This isn't entirely correct.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I found some faults in original logic, namely if finish was located before scooters and there were steps between the remaining scooters. I modified the example to take these in account and provided examples.

Comment: @LTJ should we move `steps += max(0, scooters[i] - scooters[i - 1] - 10)` after the statement `if finish in (scooters[i], scooters[i - 1]):`  This will address the edge case where `scooter[0] = finish.`

Comment: That does make sense, I'll edit the answer. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by counting the number of steps which cannot be taken by scooter. You can do this by creating a list of all the steps that need to be made, populating it with 1s. Then set to 0 any step that can be taken by a scooter. The number of walking steps is then the sum of the list:

```py
def solution(finish, scooters):
    steps = [1 for _ in range(finish+1)]
    zeros = [0 for _ in range(11)]
    for s in scooters:
        steps[s:s+11] = zeros
    return sum(steps)

solution(27, [15, 7, 3, 10])
# 5
solution(23, [7,4,14])
# 4
```

Comment: Not feasible for a large value of `finish`, which is typical for competitive programming questions

Comment: @AbhinavMathur most computers have enough memory for a pretty big list of integers...

Comment: While that might be true, most algorithmic questions on practice platforms like LeetCode have a time limit specified.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur because the sort is `O(nlogn)` and this is `O(31n)` (assuming the number of scooters is about 1/10 the value of finish) there is actually a point  at which this solution becomes faster. On my old laptop, that is around the 10,000,000 mark.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple approach, you can just iterate over the `scooters` array, and increment steps based on the distance between the `i-th` scooter and the `i+1-th` scooter.

```py
def solution(finish, scooters):
    i = 0
    n = len(scooters)
    scooters.sort()
    steps = min(scooters[0], finish)
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        if scooters[i] + 10 >= finish:
            break
        elif scooters[i+1] > finish:
            steps += max(0, finish-scooters[i]-10)
        else:
            steps += max(0, scooters[i+1]-scooters[i]-10)
    if scooters[-1] < finish:
        steps += max(0, finish - scooters[-1] - 10)
    return steps

print(solution(27, [15, 7, 3, 10]))
print(solution(23, [7,4,14]))
```

Time complexity: `O(nlogn)` where `n` is the length of `scooters` array.